# Como Mostrar na tela um resultado de divisão

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em que o resultado da divisão dos 5 itens sempre da 0, alguém pode me ajudar a arrumar

```
private void btnCalcu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //convertendo
        Total = Convert.ToInt32(txtFechado.Text); 
        SemInt = Convert.ToInt32(txtSemInt.Text);
        LigDepois = Convert.ToInt32(txtLigaDps.Text);
        Negoc = Convert.ToInt32(txtNegoc.Text);
        Agend = Convert.ToInt32(txtAgend.Text);

        //Calculando

        totalLig = Total + SemInt + LigDepois + Negoc + Agend;
        porc = (Total/100) * totalLig;
        TotPoc = Convert.ToDouble(porc);
        MessageBox.Show("Total de ligações é: " + totalLig + " Pocentual é : " +TotPoc );



    }
```

Comment: Isso não estará relacionado com os valores que está a usar no cálculo?

Comment: @JoãoMartins, o `TotPoc` não, mas o `totalLig` sim isso que é estranho, não sei se estou errando na logica da conta ou o que

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e coloque os valores de exemplo que está a utilizar, se calhar assim chegamos a uma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz uma divisão entre dois inteiros (int), o resultado vai ser inteiro..

ex: 8 / 10 = 0

se você quiser 0.8 terá que converter um dos valores para double, ou outro tipo que aceite valores decimais..

ex:

```
double TotPoc = ((double)Total/100) * totalLig;
```

Já que você usa o 100 pode usar o [sufixo](https://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix) **D**

ficaria assim:

```
  double TotPoc = (Total/100D) * totalLig;
```

Outra coisa seria quando recebe valores vindo do usuario seria usar o [int.TryParse](https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse) em vez de `Convert.ToInt32`